# Unable to understand meaning of 'Partially visible'

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am trying to understand android activity life cycle.

Official documentation states:

Pause Your Activity:

When the system calls onPause() for your activity, it technically means your activity is still partially visible.

I created an activity and then moved to another activity using intent.During debugging I see that first activity's onPause() is indeed called.But I don't understand what does it mean for activity to be partially visible because when other activity is visible(and first activity is paused) then first activity is not visible at all.

With regards

Manish

Answer (score 1):

**to be partially visible**  is like for situation like poping a dialog themed Activity up over your Activity means that the activity is visible for user even it lost interaction with user. onPause() will run in Activity Transitions and after that when its no longer visible by user , onStop() will call.

Comment: Technically, it would take a dialog-themed `Activity`, not a `Dialog`. A `Dialog` is considered part of the activity that creates it, and showing one does not trigger lifecycle events. But a dialog-themed `Activity` would still allow the underlying activity to be visible around the edges, while also triggering `onPause()`.

Comment: Arash, but in my test app first activity is in paused state, so it must be visible at least to some extent.But it is not visible at all and new activity is all over.So how is first activity partially visible.

Comment: @CommonsWare : its true Commonsware ;),Thanks to mention that and i've edited the answer

Comment: @user2444661: `onPause()` is called once your activity no longer in the foreground from an input standpoint. In the case of a dialog-themed `Activity` having taken over the foreground, your activity will only be called with `onPause()`. In the case of a full-screen activity having taken over the foreground, your activity will be called with `onPause()`, followed shortly by `onStop()`. `onStop()` means that the activity is no longer visible.

Comment: @user2444661 : Commonsware completly answered your question , and its just perfect.

Comment: Commonsware, I put both onPause() and onStop() in my first activity.During debugging I found that when next activity(full screen activity) is called using intent, then only onPause() is called for first activity.onStop is not at all called.